# Changing pull light switch

Tags: wiring, switch

I have a faulty pull light switch from a house built in the 1970s.  When removing the casing i find 3 pairs of wires - please see picture.

This switch controls a light and also an extractor fan.  The replacement switch i purchased only has L1, L2 and Common terminals.  Can anybody please help me with how I can replace this switch?  Did I buy the wrong replacement switch or do I need to introduce some other connections before the new switch?

[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I am in the United Kingdom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old pull-switch appears to switch both hot/live and neutral wires to your light and extractor fan.
Unless specifically required in your location (judging by the wire colors probably UK/Europe?) it isn't really necessary to switch neutral, so your new switch can be used here.

You'll need to connect all the neutral (black) wires together using whatever method is standard in your location (screw-terminal blocks, push-in connectors, wire-nuts, etc).
Then on to the hot/live (red) wires. The pair which are together in one hole on your old switch must stay together on your new switch.
You'll be using the Common terminal and either the L1 or L2 terminal. The paired red wires together on Common and the lone red wire on L1 or L2.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to confirm i am in the UK, is this something I can do with confidence, whats the risk if the wiring isnt as you expect it to be?

Comment: Nevermind - all good thanks!